# Why is the triton language faster than pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, nvidia, openai-api

[This](https://openai.com/blog/triton/) blog, introducing OpenAI's new python extension called Triton, says this about why Triton can do matrix math faster than pytorch (referring to an an example of how Triton can be used to compute Softmax along the rows of an m by n matrix)

> Importantly, this particular implementation of softmax keeps the rows of X in SRAM throughout the entire normalization process, which maximizes data reuse when applicable (~<32K columns). This differs from PyTorch’s internal CUDA code, whose use of temporary memory makes it more general but significantly slower (below). The bottom line here is not that Triton is inherently better, but that it simplifies the development of specialized kernels that can be much faster than those found in general-purpose libraries.

1. How does pytorch allocate memory for device tensors, what is the "temporary memory" being referred to here? Why is the use of this temporary memory more general, but slower than use of SRAM?
2. Is SRAM here referring to cache memory? If so, how/why does this library make better use of cache memory than pytorch internals? My understanding is that the decision about what data to cache is mostly up to the hardware rather than software.

Answer (score 1):

"temporary memory" refers to HBM, or DRAM, or VRAM, which is the main memory of a graphic card. For example, the 40GB memory on an A100.

The SRAM is generally the cache memory, the on-chip memory, which is significantly faster than HBM, the off-chip memory.

In triton, you can use the `tl.load` function to explicitly load data from HBM to SRAM, and use `tl.save` function to explicitly save data from SRAM to HBM.

Since the SRAM is faster, but smaller than the HBM. One common practice of developing triton kernel is to load a small chunk of a bigger matrix or tensor, then do as many operations as possible, and then save it back to HBM. This trick is often called a **fused** kernel.

To illustrate the above statement, here is a picture from FlashAttention, which is an algorithm for fused attention.

[image: Flash Attention]